# Create an array from a string in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, integer

How do I create an array of integers from a variable containing the string "3 4 5 4 3"?

Comment: What have you tried, and in what way(s) has it not worked? Please don't just ask for an answer with no demonstration of attempting it yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I prefer:

```
[int[]] -split "3 4 5  4   3"
```

`-split` handles whitespace space better than `String.Split()`.  With `String.Split()`, if there is more than one space between numbers you wind up with empty strings in the generated array. The empty strings are coerced to 0 by PowerShell e.g.:

```
C:\PS> [int[]]"3 4 5  4   3".Split()
3
4
5
0
4
0
0
3
```

Answer (score 5):

Splitting the string creates an array of string, add a cast to an array of integers:

```
[int[]]"3 4 5 4 3".Split()
```